# Diving a polygon into 6 equal regions

Tags: mathematics, geometry

You are given a convex polygon, ie all its internal angles are less than 180 degrees. Prove that you can always draw three straight lines through a point inside this polygon, such that they divide it into 6 equal (by area) regions? **Bonus questions:**

- Can you prove that this can be achieved for non-convex polygons too? This time the point may not lie inside the polygon.
- Does this result extend to 4 lines dividing a convex polygon into 8 equal regions?

This puzzle was inspired by the hard problem in the recent TopCoder Open Algorithm final, written by Michal Forisek (misof).

Comment: I see ok. Probably belongs on different site.

Comment: I have a solution, if you repost to math.stackexchange.

Comment: Done https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444763/dividing-a-convex-polygon-into-6-equal-regions